# Remove row from custom ListView JSONArray.remove(int) undefined

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and I populate it with a custom view using an Adapter of JSONArray. In each row I have a button to delete that row, but I dont know how to do it.

```
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);  
            ad.setCancelable(false);
            ad.setMessage("Are you sure?");  
            ad.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                    //jsonArray.remove(position);
                }
            });
```

The `jsonArray.remove(position)` is said `undefined for the type` and `Cannot refer to a non-final variable position inside an inner class defined in a different method`

The begin of my Adapter is like this:

```
class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private final JSONArray jsonArray;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final Context context;
    private Button pay, cancel;

    public JSONAdapter(Context context, JSONArray jsonArray) {
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

So any idea of how can I remove it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSONArray` class doesn't have a `remove` method so trying to call it on `jsonArray` will obviously not work. Without seeing the full code of your adapter I would say you have two options:

1. Extract all the data from the `jsonArray` object into an `ArrayList`(you could use a simple data holder class if you have several values) and use that `ArrayList` in the `JSONAdapter`. Then you can easily remove elements from the list when you click the `Button` by removing items in the `ArrayList`.
2. You could also use the `jsonArray` like you do now and then keep a reference to the number of rows deleted plus the exact row that should be deleted. Then in your adapter you would have to rewrite the `getCount` and `getItem` methods to eliminate the "deleted" rows. So, in this situation you will not actually delete rows, you would just make them appear as deleted.

I would go with option one.

Comment: Thank so much for your reply. I know JSONArray don't have a remove method, I just put it in there because I saw some people in other questions 'solving' it like that. And thanks to your reply I had an idea to solve. What I basically did was to create a remove method on my adapter which parse the JSONArray into a List, remove, and then make the way back (I know it is not option 1, but option 1 would require more changing in my code). Thanks again mate.